# how to use http to return the status of a url

Tags: javascript, http, axios, ky

I am building a tool that makes a http request to various endpoints and returns the status code.

Using axios.get on an endpoint such as https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users returns a 200 which is great, but when I try my tool out on facebook.com I get a `request failed with status code 404'`, what am I doing wrong?

It seems the request url is http://localhost:5173/www.facebook.com, so my localhost is being added to the url?

```
import ky from "ky";

export const useFetchStatus = async (url: string) => {
  const response = await ky.get(url);
  console.log(response.status);
  return response.status;
};
```

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "preact/hooks";
import { useFetchStatus } from "./hooks/hooks";

export const App = () => {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState(0);

  const url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users";

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(async () => {
      const status = await useFetchStatus(url);
      setStatus(status);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
  }, []);

  return <>Status: {status}</>;
};
```

Comment: If you make the request to `https://www.facebook.com`, you'd likely see a different response (maybe not a 200, but hopefully not a 404). I don't know what `ky` is, but `url` doesn't have `http://` (or `https://`), it looks like it gets appended to your current URL.

Comment: If you don’t actually want to download any html while making your request (just the status code) consider [HEAD](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) instead of GET.

Comment: ky is just a light http library. Axios returns the same result.

Comment: Head works great, thanks. 
Tim Lewis, working now that I have added http:// (or https://). Thanks